# Add Buttons in Sharepoint Library

Tags: button, sharepoint-2010

I would like to know whether it is possible to add buttons to a particular document library's column when a new item is created.
 I am working on `SharePoint` without using any development tools like `SPD` and `Visual Studio`.So, is there any way to use JavaScript to achieve this? Because, if it is done using java script I can add the java script code to a content editor and get the desired functionality.

What are the any/other ways to achieve this functionality by coding in `visual studio`?

Thanks

Comment: To give more inputs, I am trying to add a button to the default view of the library and on the click of the button I would like to start a workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *might* be able to achieve it with JavaScript as you suggest. However, **don't do it**. SharePoint is a complicated product with very complicated means for displaying lists. Don't try to hack it, rather use the appropriate tools (i.e. Visual Studio and/or SharePoint Designer).

To achieve what you want, you will have to create a [custom field type definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415141%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and an appropriate [XSLT rendering template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff606773%28v=office.14%29.aspx). However, this is both quite complicated. I would recommend either creating a custom list item menu action or a custom button in the ribbon.

Comment: Use javascript to customize SharePoint is not a hack. You consider all SharePoint Javascript object model as a hack? It is pretty common scenario when you want to add some UI customization using javascript and content editor web part. Create custom fields might not be applicable solution if you want to modify behavior of standard fields.

Comment: I'm not saying using JavaScript is a hack. What I'm saying is that mangling with a list view using JavaScript is a hack. The OP will — most likely — need some state information and/or other fields from each list item, probably not shown in the list view, so using JavaScript it would be like 1) standard rendering, 2) querying the list again for each item to read required state data, 3) modifying the rendered output ex-post.

Comment: Sharepoint is a hack. So I think using javascript to "mangle" the list view is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Is the custom drop-down menu which you have recommended is the list item menu?

Comment: @Hulk Yes, that's it. Sorry for a confusing term, fixed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio you have several options. I expect you need to add buttons to the list form (Edit or Display). You can:

1. create custom ribbon buttons. - The most standard way.
2. create your own field with the button you need and use this column in the list. Little bit complicated. Can be used in more lists.
3. create your own Editform for your content type or list. - The most complicated way but with the most possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried the option of adding custom ribbon button using SharePoint designer. I found the procedure very easy than using visual studio which requires a SharePoint farm installed to customize.